# SQL Aggregation in oracle 11g or 19 version using duplicate columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I'm making SQL but I need your help.
I'm currently using oracle 19 version or upper 11g version I guess so.
This my sql and the result below.

[SQL]
SELECT
SUM_DT
, SUM_SUBJ_CL_CD
, SUM_SUBJ_NO
, (SELECT INST_NM FROM TB_FNC_INST WHERE INST_ID = SUM_SUBJ_NO) AS INST_NM
, TRX_CNT
FROM TS_DAY_TRX_SUM
WHERE SUM_DT = '20230509'
AND SUM_SUBJ_CL_CD = '8';

[DATA]
SUM_DT  SUM_SUBJ_CL_CD   myCol1    myCol2    myCol3
1  20230509       8         I000000001   A         1
2  20230509       8         I000000002   B         13
3  20230509       8         I000000003   C         8

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNZGe.png)

But I want to the data to be like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8YEJ.png)

[DATA]
SUM_DT SUM_SUBJ_CL_CD     col1     col2  col3   col4      col5   col6     col7      col8    col9
20230509     8         I000000001   A     1   I000000002    B      13   I000000003   C        8

How can I make this? I'm looking for PIVOT function in oracle but I couldn't figure it out.

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT
SUM_DT
, SUM_SUBJ_CL_CD
, SUM_SUBJ_NO
, (SELECT INST_NM FROM TB_FNC_INST WHERE INST_ID = SUM_SUBJ_NO) AS INST_NM
, TRX_CNT
FROM TS_DAY_TRX_SUM
WHERE SUM_DT = '20230509'
AND SUM_SUBJ_CL_CD = '8'
)
PIVOT(
MAX(TRX_CNT)
FOR (SUM_SUBJ_CL_CD) IN ('8')
);